# Custom profile fields are not being displayed on user edit page in drupal 6

Tags: users

I have created some custom field to user profiles like address, phone no etc. It is configured to display these field during registration. It works well. My problem is these fields are not being displayed on user edit page (user/5/edit). Is there any way i can display the fields on user edit page. I am using drupal 6.

Comment: Are you using Display Suite?

Comment: No i am not using display suite

Comment: Problem solved. I didn't knew it appears in a different tab. The tab links were hidden

Comment: answer the question then close it. Earn some reps at least.